# Would changing a package name that contains classes affect Firebase analytics?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I have an Android app already on production that uses Firebase. Some packages where named using underscores. i.e

```
com.mobile.myapp
├───foo_package
│    FooFragment.kt
|    FooActivity.kt
├───bar_package
│    BarFragment.kt
|    BarActivity.kt
├───bazpackage
│    BazFragment.kt
|    BazActivity.kt
```

According to [Kotlin's code conventions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coding-conventions.html#naming-rules), there shouldn't be any underscores in package names.

Would changing `foo_package` and `bar_package` names affect/reset any of the analytics in some regard?
For instance, the `screen_view` events, user engagement metrics, crash reports, custom events etc.

Answer (score 0):

Do you see the full package name anywhere in the console?  If so, then changing it will probably cause you problems.  You should instead [manually track your screens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/screenviews#manually_track_screens) using the provided API, so that changing the names of classes won't change your analytics.